# What should be the best plan for me to lose fat and gain muscle

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, strength-training

3 months ago I joined a gym. I am following a diet and doing mostly cardio workouts.

To date I have lost 5-6kg (I weighed 85kg before I started).

I have a couple of questions:

1. Should I continue with my current plan?
2. I need to gain muscle, and I'm taking whey protein to help. What else can I do?
3. Should I first focus on losing weight and then gaining muscle, gaining muscle and then losing weight, or both at the same time?

Comment: Can you break up your statement into defined questions? There are a lot of questions here, can you focus down on just one or two? Cut out the part about your knee, the answer will be "go visit a doctor".

Comment: updated my question ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Recently(3 months) joined gym, I am following diet and doing workout (mostly cardio).

Excellent progress.

#### Till date i have lost 5-6 kg(85kg before) Should i continue with my plan?

Depends on your specific long-term goals.

#### Also i need to muscle gain, taking whey protein (for same?).

IF you take whey protein you will have more protein in your system which can be used to build muscle when paired with weightlifting if you are not getting enough in your diet.

It is not a magic substance that creates muscles, it has to be balanced in your diet like all food and supplements. You probably want to achieve  0.64lbs/0.82g protein per pound of body weight per day.

#### Also i have query whether i first lose weight then gain muscle or both goes hand in hand:

Initially they will happen at the same time but your weight loss will plateau at some point and your maximum lifting weight will do the same. At that point you should focus on cutting (less calories with same/similar weight) or bulking (more calories, combined with heavier weights to aid recovery).

Answer (score 2):

**Recently(3 months) joined gym, I am following diet and doing workout (mostly cardio). Till date i have lost 5-6 kg(85kg before), mainly following diet.**

That's decent weight loss and progress. Keep it up?

**Does i have injured my knee forever?**

Don't know. Go see a doctor.

**Also i have query whether i first lose weight then gain muscle or both goes hand in hand?**

Generally, you'd have periods of "cutting"(losing weight) and "bulking"(gaining weight). With the first, you aim at a calorie deficit, however not too big(because then you will lose muscle). On the second, you aim at a calorie surplus with a good macro balance(proportion of protein, good carbs and healthy fats)

Answer (score 0):

The New York Times (and other media) recently [reported the results of a study](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/02/health/biggest-loser-weight-loss.html) which followed the winners of the "Biggest Losers" weight loss reality TV show for 6 years. Most of them regained most of their weight, despite their proven willpower and knowledge, which certainly must be far above average. (Some of the neurological aspects are covered [in another article.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/08/opinion/sunday/why-you-cant-lose-weight-on-a-diet.html))

What I take away for the average person from these relatively new findings is:

- Our knowledge about the interactions between exercise, nutrition, weight, metabolism, our psyche and health is still incomplete.
- Don't stress out about anything.
- Do exercise as much as is fun.
- Make moderate changes to your diet. Focus on diversity above all else. Avoid explicit dieting.
- Do not try to fundamentally change your body. The attempt is bound to fail long-term. Instead, make gradual changes which just stop the creeping weight gain.

Comment: While I normally like the articles in the NYT, I can't believe the amount of self-serving drivel in this article. That said there are some good points about how losing weight and keeping it off is a big lifestyle change. I cannot believe I am reading "Do not try to fundamentally change your body" on PFStack

Comment: @JJosaur "Do not try to fundamentally change your body": True, it is a funny statement here :-). Of course I'm not a regular and as an outsider probably have a different perspective. I was seeing this question on the Hot List and after reading "I joined the gym 3 months ago" thought I'd share the article which I found noticeable. (You are right about the quality -- the original report I had read which is linked now was better.) Obviously there are people who succeed with fundamental long-term changes, but they are not many and the sustained effort needed will make it a big deal in their life.